# Set more lines than maximum in GVim

Tags: vim

I want to set 58 lines. When I type

`:set lines=58`

it shrinks to 54 lines.

Comment: Irrespective of the quality of the post, one should not include random text to pass the quality filter. There's always something that can be improved.

Comment: Would 58 lines make the window too big (vertically) to fit on the screen?

Comment: Maximize you GVim window. Examine the value of `lines`. That should tell you the maximum value of `lines` you can use.

Comment: please report the output of  `:set ghr?`

Comment: It's probably because 58 lines don't fit in your monitor? Try reducing the font size by one point.

Comment: @hexafraction: But there apparently is not always something to pass the quality filter. Believe me, I've tried almost an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kent implied, the solution is to set guiheadroom to zero.

```
:set ghr=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number of lines is determined by the size of your display / screen. Depending on font size you probably cannot fit 58 lines, therefore GVim automatically shrinks that value to 54. Try reducing your font size or increasing your display resolution (if you have that as an option).

Comment: The problem is, 54 lines is not 100 percent of screen, but rather roughly 80 percent.